# Create folders with names of files present in folder then move those files in each of that folder

Tags: bash, terminal, sh

I have different files present in `abc` folder (extension is different for each file), I want to create folders based on the name of files present in that folder and move those files to respective folders.
Eg:

Folder `abc` has

```
2.0261fc5a.js.1
22b8a.0cb8dc71bas.map
318a.fa1253sdfde99265.js.map.1
s3ds.asdasg.asfgsf.afasdf.sd
```

files with unique names.

I want to create

`2.0261fc5a.js.1` folder and move `2.0261fc5a.js.1` file  in that folder
Similarly this should happen for all files.
I did little bit of research and found this solution.

```
tmp=`mktemp -d tmp_XXXXXX` || exit 1
for i in *
do
  mv "$i" $tmp
done
mv $tmp/* .
rm -r $tmp
```

But this gives error as
`mv: cannot move 'tmp_RwK2xZ' to a subdirectory of itself, 'tmp_RwK2xZ/tmp_RwK2xZ'`

Could you guys please help with this ?

Comment: Simply put, you can't name a directory the same exact name as the file you intend putting within it.

Comment: Hey @l'L'l Could you please elaborate

Comment: You are trying to move the directory `mktemp` made into itself. You'll want to actually move your file named similarly into the directory instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a tmp *file* not a tmp *dir*

```sh
tmpfile=$(mktemp)   # TODO, check this exists on the same filesystem,
                    # or provide a template argument
for file in *; do
  if [[ $file != "$tmpfile" ]]; then
    mv "$file" "$tmpfile"
    mkdir "$file"         # TODO check for failure
    mv "$tmpfile" "$file/$file"
  fi
done
```

Left to do: error messaging and re-renaming files if things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find` perhaps:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} {}_temp \; -exec mkdir {} \; -execdir mv {}_temp {}/{} \;
```

Essentially what this command does for a file named `abc`:

```
mv ./abc ./abc_temp
mkdir ./abc
mv ./abc_temp ./abc/./abc
```

Renames the file by adding `_temp`, creates a directory named as the original file and finally renames the temporary file back as it's moved into the directory.

Answer (score 0):

For each element *fname* in the current directory:

- If that element is a file: `if [ -f $fname ]`
- Move the file to `/tmp` temporarily: `mv $fname /tmp`
- Create a directory with the same name as *fname*: `mkdir $fname`
- Move *fname* into that directory: `mv /tmp/$fname ./$fname/`

```sh
for fname in *
do
    if [ -f "$fname" ]
    then
        mv "$fname" /tmp
        mkdir "$fname"
        mv "/tmp/$fname" "./$fname/"
    fi
done
```

#### Why the double quotes everywhere?

Spaces, Spaces, Spaces. Sometimes filenames have spaces. That makes [problems](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086). Double quotes are the solution.

#### What is `/tmp`

We move the file from the current directory to the temp directory so that it does not conflict with the folder we are about to create with the same name. We don't have to create a new file or folder to store anything because the [linux /tmp](https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/tmp.html) exists for exactly that purpose. To temporarily store random stuff :)

Comment: You should *double quote* the command in the `for` loop declaration (`$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)`) in order to avoid [word splitting](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086).

Comment: Good catch! I actually found it easier to use `*` and then check if the element was a file